# 502 Bad Gateway, cURL request to API Platform, Symfony

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose

I'm making a `cURL` request

```
curl -X 'POST' \
'http://localhost:8013/api/superheros' \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
 "name": "Clark Kent",
 "slug": "supermman",
 "featured": true,
 "createdAt": "2021-10-11T11:48:22.366Z"
}'
```

to an API endpoint on my local above. I receive a 502 bad gateway error.

[image]

I'm using Docker for all intents and purposes.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app1
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app1
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver1:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver1
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8013:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db1:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db1
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3318:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: rest_api
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

**app.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

I've read people saying that `PHP-FPM` isn't running but my `Dockerfile` clearly uses it. Are you able to offer some clues?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass arguments to `php-fpm` in your Dockerfile as below, and make sure `9000` port is configured in `local.ini`

```
CMD ["php-fpm", "-F", "-y", "/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini"]
```

- `-F` force `php-fpm` running in foreground
- `-y` sepcify the config path

After Dockerfile modified, you need to run `docker-compose build` to rebuild docker image

Comment: Same thing, following a `docker-compose down/up` - bad gateway

Comment: maybe you can run `netstat -an` command in php-fpm container to check if php-fpm running at port 9000,

Comment: Please see my edit. I don't see the figure `9000` anywhere from your suggested command?

Comment: port 9000 need to be configured in `php/conf.d/loca.ini`, and make sure to rebuild docker image after modifying the Dockerfile

Comment: Do you have the syntax for configuring port 9000 please?

Comment: you can check if `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`  presented in local.ini